# Force qmake to error out when reading undefined variables

Tags: qt, qmake

I need to force qmake to be have like `set -eu` in bash, where this:

```
$ bash -eu -c 'echo $FOO; echo Carrying on'
bash: FOO: unbound variable
$ echo $?
1
```

results in a failure, and does not print "Carrying on".

Does qmake support an option like "reading from an undefined variable is an error"?

Answer (score 1):

For qmake variables you can use `isEmpty()` as is. For checking environment variables there is a dirty hack:

```
VAR = $$(FOO)
isEmpty(VAR) {
    message(empty)
} else {
    message(FOO is $(FOO))
}
```

Test:

```
$ qmake
Project MESSAGE: empty
$ FOO=test qmake
Project MESSAGE: FOO is test
```